# ToolStripCombobox displays at the top left corner of the screen when DropDownStyle is Simple

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripdropdown, toolstripcombobox

I have a `ToolStripCombobox` that when I set its `DropDownStyle` to `Simple`. The first time which I open the menu, it displays at the top left corner of the screen. 
However, when I select the same item for the second time, it displays in the correct location.

Is there a way to prevent the code from showing the list at the top left corner of the screen?

Thank you in advance for any help.

**First Time**

[image: Result 1]

**Second Time**

[image: Result 2]

Comment: I can confirm the issue. The question contains steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem put this code in the `Load` event of form:

```
var item = toolStripComboBox1;
var createControl = item.Control.Parent.GetType().GetMethod("CreateControl",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
createControl.Invoke(item.Control.Parent, new object[] { true });
```

It's a strange bug and I don't have any idea why the `ToolStripComboBox` with `DisplayStyle` set to `Simple` suffers from this bug but by setting `DisplayStyle` to `DropDown` or `DropDownList` doesn't have this bug.

Using above code, I forced the owner `ToolStripDropDownMenu` be created before being shown.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you Reza. Also, thank you for editing the question too.

Comment: BTW, When you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: Hi Reza, I did it the first time, but I did not have enough reputation. Now I do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the ToolStripCombobox style to Dropdown in design mode and then to Simple in the form's load event, I was able to get it to open properly.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the `SelectedIndex` on a `ToolStripComboBox` before it's parent object's `Click` event is being called will cause this issue.

In my case the parent object was a `ToolStripMenuItem`. When modifying the `SelectedIndex` in the `Click` event of the `ToolStripMenuItem`, the issue was fixed.

I only encountered this issue in `.NET Core 3.1` and not in `.NET 4.x`.